# Given a six sided dice with a serie of rolled values, what is the probability of getting 1 in the next roll

Tags: probability, dice

The probability of rolling a 1 with the next dice roll is 1/6.

But, given this serie of previous rolls:
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Is there anyway to calculate a probability (or other term), given this particular history of previous rolls, taking the previous rolls into account and saying it is more likely to get a 1 since the last 10 rolls did not give you a 1.

Is there anyway to calculate such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The die is not some cognitive agent that can effect the outcome of it being thrown based on any memory of past events; the die has no memory, and no control.

So, it does not matter what the previous outcomes were. Assuming the die is fair, each outcome for any throw is equally likely, i.e. it's $1$ in $6$

To think that it is more likely to come up with a $1$ now that it hasn't come up with a $1$ for a while is called the Gambler's Fallacy. Look it up!

Comment: Thanks, [Wikipedia on Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) gave a pretty good view on the matter.

Comment: In fact a rational conclusion from seeing a very long string of rolls without a $1$ is that the die is biased against showing $1$ and that it is _less_ likely to get a $1$ on the next roll.

Comment: @DavidK i hope you will forgive this slightly off-topic comment but you should check out this XKCD comic about jumping off a bridge :D https://xkcd.com/1170/